# Multiple elements inline with full width button that collapses (Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a responsive calendar that shows extra info on a "well" when you click on the name (collapsable).

And I want the button to be full-width along with the date and icon on the same line, but even when I'm using Bootstrap grid it keeps making it in blocks.

What can I do to wrap all on the same line and make the collapsable "well" appear below?

This is an example of one event:

```
<!--Event 1-->     
    <div class="row">
     <div class="div-event">
      <span class="date-event col-xs-2 col-sm-2"><span class="num-date-event">22</span>    <br>SEP</span>

      <button class="btn btn-event btn-block col-xs-8 col-sm-8" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1">Katy's Super Party<br>at her house</button>

      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift icon-event col-xs-2 col-sm-2" aria-     hidden="true"><span class="text-event"><br>PARTY</span></span>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-1"> 
        <div class="well">
          ...
        </div>
        </div> 
     </div>
     </div>
```

And here is the fiddle of the calendar:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrndrmrj/6/

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in css `width: 65%` in `btn-block` and remove `margin-top: -19px` in `btn-event`

http://jsfiddle.net/mrndrmrj/9/

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH sir! I was desperate for that! Just for learning purposes, what does "width: 65%" did? @JMusic

Comment: @AlejandroArdavín to be honest I don't really know why this was problem but working with bootstrap sometimes just have to mess around with some settings and it will work. Even with hundreds hours working with that I still get that weird troubles weekly. :) 100% width did force it to be on full width even that grid was set right.